# Is it true that PCI-E connections were initially connected to the Sourthbridge of the motherboard?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, pci-express

I read in an article from 2007 called "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory" that the PCI-e connections were connected to the Southbridge chip in contrast with AGP connections which were connected to the Northbridge chip.

Is this true? If yes what was the reason for which the PCIE connections were connected to the Sourhbridge because the Southbridge is slower than Northbridge?

Comment: This is not ture, but with exceptions. Around 2007 north bridge usually only has 20x lanes so to support dual 16X SLI there has been designs to use a second north bridge with integrated south bridge as a "big" south bridge to provide additional 20x lanes for the second 16X slot. It's not a big thing because GPU didn't really full 16X lanes anyway, and that CPU->NB1->NB2 isn't very efficient, either.

Answer (score 2):

For a lot of devices PCIe is perfectly fine going through various bridges as they simply don't have the intense memory dependence and bandwidth requirements. If the situation can tolerate a few nanoseconds more for it to traverse a north/south bridge link then there is no reason to connect the device directly to the North bridge or CPU, you connect it where there is spare connectivity.

A PCIe x1 soundcard for example would have fairly light bandwidth requirements, does not require nanosecond level response timings and quite frankly could probably tolerate being controlled over a couple of "wires" made from wet string.

A graphics card on the other hand *does* require good latency and regular large transfers of data, so you put it close to the memory and CPU.

Just because you can put a PCIe bus at the end of a north/south bridge chain doesn't mean that that is your *only* PCIe bus in the system.